# What is the importance of the Hostname when setting up a VPS?

Tags: vps, hostname

I am setting up a VPS and I was wondering how important the hostname i.e. name.domain.com is when setting it up?

For example the server is most likely going to be for my studio so it will host a number of sites on it. Yet with the hostname I can obviously only set 1 domain name.

If I do have multiple domains on the server will this have a negative impact?

Thanks.

Comment: You can point as many dns entries as you want to the IP of your server.

Answer (score 2):

> If I do have multiple domains on the server will this have a negative
>   impact?

No. With name based virtual hosts or multiple IP addresses, a single host can respond with multiple services or web sites to different domain names.

Set the host name to something unique and logical. Convention is to put in DNS, so web1.example.com  or whatever resolves to it.

Answer (score 0):

DNS(hostname) is easy to remember than IP address. You can add DNS entry for the hostname pointing to IP address and able to access your server with hostname. Additionally if you are using this vps as mail server. Then you need to have rDNS entry for IP pointing to hostname(domain name).